# Made ship on order generate an error. Magento ver. 2.2.0-dev

Tags: shipping

I installed Magento 2.2.0-dev. I created a new customer and a new product. I created an order and invoicing. Everything OK. I also can hold and reorder. But when I go to put the order shipping they generate a error. And don't let me do it.

Exception #0 (RuntimeException): Renderer for type "simple" does not exist.
 Any ideas.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Magento v2.2.0-dev is not a stable version. Suffix **-dev** tells you that it's used only for Magento Core development purposes. It may work tomorrow after the issue is fixed, but also it may not work 7 days from now because of new commits.

That's why you should work only with stable versions, like [Magento CE v2.1.5](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/ReleaseNotes2.1.5CE.html).

Answer (score 1):

This is known issue and has appeared of merging [PR #8353](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/8353) but it already fixed on develop branch [96de0c6](https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/96de0c66c105140bfdb4c671feaab0a5dbf95ca5).

Try to get latest develop branch and clear `generated` and `var` directories, if the issue is still present, please, create a new issue on Magento2 GitHub.